# Swift 5 : How do you pass a function to run inside a function () Noobie in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, parameters

How can i pass a function to run inside a function when passing it inside a parameter? .. as example

```
func thisDelay(_ passFunc:() ){//
        let seconds = 5.0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
            passFunc
            print("test2")
        }

thisDelay(print("Hello"))

//..Hello (is printed right away)
//.. test2 (is printed after 5 seconds)

// As seen Hello is printed right away .. shouldn't it been delayed with 5 sec?
```

Comment: Passing function as a completion block will help you. like -> **(_ passFunc: @escaping () -> Void )** and then calling it inside asynAfter like **passFunc()**

Comment: You are not passing a function, and `passFunc` is not typed as a function (it is a Void). Also, in `thisDelay` you are not _calling_ `passFunc`, you are just saying its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to list everything that's wrong with your code...

- In the line `thisDelay(print("Hello"))`, you are not passing any function. You're just printing, right then, as you call `thisDelay`.
- In the declaration of `thisDelay`, the parameter `passFunc` is not typed as a function; it is a Void.
- In the body of `thisDelay`, you are not *calling* `passFunc` (which you cannot do in any case, as it is not a function); you are just saying its name, which is useless.

You probably mean something like this:

```
func thisDelay(_ passFunc: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let seconds = 5.0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        passFunc()
        print("test2")
    }
}
thisDelay { print("Hello") }
```

Comment: But for a _real_ `delay` implementation see my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861